# How to return values from second screen to first screen

Tags: react-native, global-variables

I am doing a highschool project and need to get input from a second screen and display them on my first screen using react native. Whenever I try to bring the values from screen 2 to screen 1 it just gives me a blank and a hook error. I declared the values globally on their own .js file for each value

Screen 2

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { TextInput, View, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import ModalDropdown from 'react-native-modal-dropdown';
import BookTitle from "../values/bookTitle";

const [TitleBook, setTitleBook] = useState('')

const AddBookPage = ({navigation}) =>{
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>Enter The Book's Title</Text>
            <TextInput placeholder="Book's Title" onChangeText={newtext => setTitleBook(newtext)}></TextInput>
            <Text>Enter The Book's Author</Text>
            <TextInput placeholder="Book's Author"></TextInput>
            <ModalDropdown options={['Fiction', 'Non-Fiction', 'Fantasy', 'Mystery', 'Educational']}/>
            <Text>Enter The Book's Number Of Pages </Text>
            <TextInput placeholder="0"></TextInput>

            <Button title="Add Book" onPress={ () => {
                BookTitle = TitleBook;
                navigation.navigate('Home');
            }}></Button>
        </View>
    )
};

export default AddBookPage;
```

Screen 1

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import BookTitle from '../values/bookTitle';

const HomePage = ({navigation}) =>{
    return(
        <View>
            <Button title='Add A Book' onPress={ () => {
                navigation.navigate('AddBook');
                }}></Button>
            <Button title='Genre'></Button>
            <Button title='History'></Button>

            <Text>User Profile</Text>
            <Text>Last Read Book : {BookTitle}</Text>
            <Text>Book Author : </Text>
            <Text>Book Genre : </Text>
            <Text>Book Total Pages : </Text>

            <Text>Total Number Of Pages Read Across All Books : </Text>
            <Text>Average Number Of Pages Read Across All Books : </Text>

        </View>
    )
};

export default HomePage;
```

How can I take my values from screen 2 and put them on screen 1

I tried decalring a global variable and making it accessible to both screens so I can manipulate it and bring it back to the home screen

Comment: I just answered this question a few days earlier. Please use the search next time.

Here is example how you can pass params between screens (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74209564/how-to-pass-value-between-pages-react-native/74239898#74239898).

Answer (score 0):

### Screen 2

You can pass data with navigation,

```
<Button title="Add Book" onPress={ () => {
                navigation.navigate('Home', {
                BookTitle : TitleBook
                });
            }}></Button>
```

### Screen 1

And get data from navigation

```
const bookTitle = navigation.params.BookTitle;
```